# Chrome.runtime.onMessage returns "undefined" even when value is known for asynchronous response

Tags: asynchronous-javascript

In my code I have a content script which requests a cookie from the background script.

Even though I can print the cookie to the Dev Tool console, the message received from background script *is always **undefined**.*

### Why?

Background script:

```
// listens for content scripts to request the cookie 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        // Respond with the value of the cookie 
        if (message === 'get-cookie') {
            chrome.cookies.get({"url": "http://www.example.com", "name": "cookie_example"}, function(cookie) {
                // prints the correct value
                console.log(cookie.value);
                sendResponse(cookie.value);
                });
             }
      });
   }
});
```

Content script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('get-cookie', (response) => {
    // logs "undefined"
    console.log(response);
    /* tries to do something useful with the response */
});
```

And returns an error

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because getting the cookie is an asynchronous action.
As per [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessage) the onMessage returns boolean or undefined. Since no boolean is returned, the onMessage returns undefined and fails with the error.

To solve the problem, **you must return a boolean value `true` to indicate the onMessage is returning an asynchronous response**. Remember to place such return at the very end of your code, outside any asynchronous requests. Anything below such return will be ignored.

Note: Returning a Promise will NOT work.

Fixed code:

Background script:

```
// listens for content scripts to request the cookie 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        // Respond with the value of the cookie 
        if (message === 'get-cookie') {
            chrome.cookies.get({"url": "http://www.example.com", "name": "cookie_example"}, function(cookie) {
                // prints the correct value
                console.log(cookie.value);
                // will send the correct value in due time
                sendResponse(cookie.value);
                });
             }
      });

     
     return true; // CRUCIAL! indicates that an asynchronous response is being processed

     /* anything here will be ignored */

   }
});
```

Content script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('get-cookie', (response) => {]
    // logs the correct value
    console.log(response);
    /* can successfully do useful things with the response */
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if your listener function is `async` it won't return true but will return a Promise. Listener functions can't be async.